# Simplification of $\sum_{a=1}^3\sigma^a_{\alpha\beta} S^a_{\gamma\delta}$ where $\sigma^a,S^a$ are representations of $SU(2)$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, group-theory, representation-theory

As the question asks, I am dealing with a problem where I'd like to simplify

$$\sum_{a=1}^3 \sigma^a_{\alpha\beta} S^a_{mn}$$
where $\sigma^a$ are the spin-1/2 Paulis and $S^a$ are some higher-spin representation of $SU(2)$. For the case where $S^a = \sigma^a$, we know
$$\sum_{a=1}^3 \sigma^a_{\alpha\beta} \sigma^a_{\gamma\delta}=2\delta_{\alpha\delta}\delta_{\beta\gamma} - \delta_{\alpha\beta}\delta_{\gamma\delta}$$

and I'm searching for a higher-spin analog of this formula. There is probably some representation-theoretic solution.

Comment: I would use different indices, e.g., m,n,  in lieu of γ,δ, indexing the *larger* space of the higher representation...

Comment: Note for spin $s\neq 1/2$ of $\vec S$, these three matrices and the Identity do not provide a complete basis for $(2s+1)\times (2s+1)$ matrices. For *s=1/2*, the Pauli matrices do, which  leads to the derivation of the Fierz identity you cite. It should then be unlikely/bizarre if anything of the sort obtained for generic *s*. Where would anything of the sort turn up? You *do* know how to "add" spin 1/2 to spin *s*, but you are asking for a virtually impossible consequence...

Comment: I could write a long-winded answer why this cannot be done, if it is not evident to you from the Fierz-mismatch of Pauli versus s-spin indices upon transposition. The "accident" that makes the Pauli-Fierzing identity work is described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Completeness_relation_2) and in the handy Appendix 29 of Okun's tasteful book Leptons and Quarks, of course. It should be evident that, for $s\neq 1/2$, the method falls flat on its face. As indicated, it is trivial to find the eigenvalues of $\vec \sigma \cdot \vec S$ on the states of spin  s-1/2 and s+1/2 ...

Answer (score 1):

Since your title asks for a mere "simplification", and not a Fierz-transposition, argued to be extraordinarily unlikely and problematic in the comments, I'll repeat the undergraduate QM procedure for your cross expression, as it summarizes the "easy" part of "adding" spins.

You have a spin doublet (2 states operated upon by the generators $\vec \sigma/2$) tensored to a multiplet of 2s+1 states acted upon by $\vec S$. So the tensor product space everything fits in is 4s+2 -dimensional. You already know this representation of SU(2) reduces to a direct sum of a 2s+2 -plet acted upon by spin s+1/2 generators, with a 2s-plet acted upon by spin s-1/2 operators. In your prototype example, you have s=1/2.

Your coproduct (composite reducible rep operators)   then squares to just
$$
(\vec {\sigma \over 2}\otimes {\mathbb I}_{2s+1} +{\mathbb I}_{2}  \otimes \vec S )^2 =\frac{3}{4} {\mathbb I}_2 \otimes {\mathbb I}_{2s+1} +s(s+1) {\mathbb I}_2 \otimes {\mathbb I}_{2s+1} + \vec \sigma \cdot \otimes \vec S, 
$$
where I have inserted the values of the quadratic Casimirs of each component representation, and the last, non diagonal term is what you are interested in.

But you also know this representation reduces through a Clebsch matrix similarity transformation to two separate blocks of the spin s+1/2 and the spin s-1/2 representations, so the above Casimir reduces to the following upon this (undisclosed!!) similarity transformation,
$$
(s^2+2s+3/4)  {\mathbb I}_{2s+2} \oplus (s^2-1/4)  {\mathbb I}_{2s} .
$$

So, regardless of the basis involved, these two expressions have an evident action when acting on the big, spin s+1/2 multiplet, and small, spin s-1/2 multiplet, respectively.

On the big multiplet, the eigenvalue of $\vec \sigma \cdot \vec S$
is
$$
-3/4- s(s+1)+ (s^2+2s+3/4)=s,
$$
whilst on all states of the the small multiplet, the eigenvalue is
$$
   -3/4- s(s+1)+ (s^2 -1/4)=-s-1 .
$$

Note for your conventional paradigm, s=1/2, the corresponding eigenvalues are the celebrated 1/2 and -3/2, respectively.